# Manually creating an HttpContext in ASP.NET Core 2.x

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, httpcontext

I'm trying to render a Razor view to a string from a Hosted Service. By using the `IRazorViewEngine` I am able to render a view to a string using something like the following:

```
 _viewEngine.FindView(actionContext, viewName, false);
var viewDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
                {
                    Model = model
                };

                var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                    actionContext,
                    viewResult.View,
                    viewDictionary,
                    new TempDataDictionary(actionContext.HttpContext, _tempDataProvider),
                    sw,
                    new HtmlHelperOptions()
                );
                viewContext.RouteData = httpContext.GetRouteData();   //set route data here

                await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);
```

However this falls apart when it is not called from a `Controller` due to missing `HttpContext`. I've tried building an HttpContext manually, but I get many errors and null exceptions deep in the Microsoft Mvc code which is extremely hard to debug. I've tried libraries like [RazorLight](https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight) which don't suit my needs because it doesn't properly support the `@inject` directive. I think my best solution is to try and mock up a fake HttpContext/ControllerContext to pass to the native ViewEngine. However, when I create a new `DefaultHttpContext`, I get a NullReferenceException around [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/04ce6cae44fb0cb11470c21769d41e3f8088e8aa/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Routing/UrlHelperBase.cs#L23), but it's very hard to trace the code and find where it is coming from.

Is there any way to create a new HttpContext?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can mock it by creating a `DefaultHttpContext`, however MVC requires some scoped services not present in the root DI scope,  so you have to create a `ServiceProvider` scope for your rendering.

Here is a sample `IHostedService` that renders a view (I did run it in the WebApplication template with MVC):

```
public class ViewRenderService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IRazorViewEngine _razorViewEngine;
    private readonly ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public ViewRenderService(IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine,
        ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _razorViewEngine = razorViewEngine;
        _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task<string> RenderToStringAsync(string viewName, object model)
    {
        using (var requestServices = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext { RequestServices = requestServices.ServiceProvider };
            var routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Home");
            var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, routeData, new ActionDescriptor());

            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                var viewResult = _razorViewEngine.FindView(actionContext, viewName, false);

                if (viewResult.View == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException($"{viewName} does not match any available view");
                }

                var viewDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
                {
                    Model = model
                };

                var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                    actionContext,
                    viewResult.View,
                    viewDictionary,
                    new TempDataDictionary(actionContext.HttpContext, _tempDataProvider),
                    sw,
                    new HtmlHelperOptions()
                );

                await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);
                return sw.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var html = await RenderToStringAsync("About", null);
        return;
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
    }
}
```

Note: This sample is based on a blog post found here, but modified to work in `IHostedService`. 
https://ppolyzos.com/2016/09/09/asp-net-core-render-view-to-string/

Comment: Thanks for your input. My code was already very similar as I had omitted some from the OP. Turns out removing  "viewContext.RouteData = httpContext.GetRouteData()" did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class YourClass 
{
   private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
   public YourClass(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
   {
      _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
   }

   public void YourMethod()
   {
      // access HttpContext with __httpContextAccessor.HttpContext
   }
}
```

And then register `IHttpContextAccessor` in the Startup class as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    // Or you can also register as follows

    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
}
```

Comment: I have tried that. The _httpContextAccessor.Context is null because my code is initiated from a hosted service which doesn't entail an HTTP request

Comment: @Brad its not `_httpContextAccessor.Context`, its `__httpContextAccessor.HttpContext`

Comment: My bad, I forgot what the specific field was but when I tried it, it was null